# Short exact sequence with missing functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

A *short exact sequence* is defined as a sequence of algebraic objects (e.g. groups) of the form
$$ 0 \longrightarrow A \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} B \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} C \longrightarrow 0$$
where $f,g$ are homomorphisms and $\text{Im}(f) = \text{Ker}(g)$. My professor said that if you have a group homomorphism $f: A\to B$, you immediately get the short exact sequence, 
$$ 0 \longrightarrow \text{ker}(f) \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow \text{im}(f) \longrightarrow 0. $$
Take, for instance, the homomorphism $\text{det} : \text{GL}_n (\mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}^\times$, the determinant function (a multiplicative homomorphism). The kernel of the function is the set of matrices with determinant $1$: the special linear group. The image of the function is the set of non-zero elements of the field $\mathbb{F}$. So we then have the sequence,
$$ 1 \longrightarrow \text{SL}_n (\mathbb{F}) \longrightarrow \text{GL}_n (\mathbb{F}) \overset{\text{det}}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{F}^\times \longrightarrow 1$$

My question is: What exactly are the functions between $1 \overset{\phi_1}\longrightarrow \text{SL}_n (\mathbb{F})$, $\text{SL}_n (\mathbb{F}) \overset{\phi_2}\longrightarrow \text{GL}_n (\mathbb{F})$, and $\mathbb{F}^\times \overset{\phi_{3}}\longrightarrow 1$? I know that the image of each $\phi_i$ must be the kernel of the next morphism (so $\text{im} (\phi_2) = \text{ker} (\text{det})$, for example). The only thing I can think of is that perhaps $\phi_{2}$ is given by the inclusion map... Could someone clarify?

Comment: $\phi_1$ can only be one thing.  Same for $\phi_3$.

Comment: and $\phi_2$ is the inclusion

Comment: @Randall So I'm assuming that $\phi_3$ is a kind of zero-map (or 1-map...) that sends each value in $\mathbb{F}^\times$ to the identity of the field. Is this right? I'm not quite sure about $\phi_{1}$, though... Any more hints?

Comment: @LukePoeppel it is the only possible homomorphism.

Comment: Just as a further comment: you started with the map det. Since you can trivially construct a matrix with any given determinant in $\mathbb{F}^\times$, det is surjective, which is the same as saying that $ \text{GL}_n (\mathbb{F}) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{\times} \rightarrow 1$ is exact.

Comment: Then you might ask yourself, what is the kernel of det? It's precisely the set of matrices with determinant 1 (the identity of $\mathbb{F}^\times$). But that's precisely $\text{SL}_n (\mathbb{F})$. Then the natural thing to do is to view $\text{SL}_n (\mathbb{F}) \subset \text{GL}_n (\mathbb{F})$ via the inclusion.

Comment: Finally, the information that "inclusion is injective" can be captured by saying that $1 \rightarrow \text{SL}_n (\mathbb{F}) \rightarrow \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}) $ is exact. Combining this all together gives your short exact sequence.

Comment: @Randall Note that $\phi_1$ is a homomorphism so it must preserve the identity. So, $\phi_1 (1) = I \in \text{SL}_{n} (\mathbb{F})$. But the image of $\phi_{1}$ is $\text{SL}_{n} (\mathbb{F})$ itself, so $\phi_{1} (1) = A$, as well, where $A$ is some *other* matrix with unit determinant. But then $\phi_{1}$ isn't a function... What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you think that the image of $\phi_1$ is $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{F})$? That is the codomain, but is definitely not the image.

Comment: @user113102 Thanks for clearing that up – it's just the trivial homomorphism! Not sure why I was thinking the image *had* to be the whole group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments given by @Randall and @user113102 (thank you!), the kernel of $f$ is obviously a subset of $A$, there is only one possibility for the functions mapping the identity to the kernel and the image to the identity: the trivial homomorphism (homomorphisms preserve identity) and the zero-map, respectively. So, for the example of the short exact sequence given by the determinant map,

$$1 \overset{\phi_1}\longrightarrow \text{SL}_n (\mathbb{F}) \overset{\phi_2}\longrightarrow \text{GL}_n (\mathbb{F}) \overset{\text{det}}\longrightarrow \mathbb{F}^\times \overset{\phi_3}\longrightarrow 1 $$

we have that $\phi_{1}: \{ 1\} \to \text{SL}_n (\mathbb{F})$ is given by $\phi_1 (1) = I$ (identity matrix), $\phi_2$ is the inclusion map, and $\phi_3 (a) = 1$ for all $a \in \mathbb{F}$, the "zero-map" (but it's multiplicative, so really the one-map).